# "on the National Mall" - why "on" and not "in"?

Tags: prepositions, in-on

From the news:

> NASA is hosting a series of events **on** the National Mall.

The National Mall is a national park, and we usually use the preposition **in**:

> The events **in** the national park were magnificent.

Here are some numbers from nytimes.com:

"on the National Mall" site:nytimes.com 1290 results

"in the National Mall" site:nytimes.com 3 results

Why doesn't the National Mall take the preposition "in" like other national parks? And what does it mean to have "on" for the National Mall?

Comment: "In the National Mall" would mean you were buried there.

Answer (score 4):

The National Mall may be a park, but it is also a [mall](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=mall) (3rd definition):

> A shady public walk or promenade.

The preposition choice used in a sentence does not usually have to do with what the object is in reality (or the various groups to which it belongs) but rather what it is being called in the phrase.  If NASA said they were hosting events in the Washington Mall National Park, the preposition would fit - but if one is hosting on a mall, then one hosts *on* it, as one cannot host *in* a shady walk.  A park, being a described area, has events held *in* it, while physical landmarks without enclosures, such as malls or hills, have events held *on* them.

As another example, consider someone who holds a picnic *on* [Mount Rainier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Rainier_National_Park) versus someone who holds one *in* Mount Rainier National Park.  One would be quite unlikely to hold a picnic *in* a mountain, regardless of whether the mountain has been designated as a national park.

Comment: The same can be said for a park in general, that a park is a shaded public walk. And this is not enough to make the park suitable for the preposition "on."